# Is info about Drupal RSS signups available?

Tags: drupal, rss, content-management-system

Is info about Drupal RSS feed signups available? 
May be some special module?
Or one only has to use feedburner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way currently within Drupal to do this. Feedburner would be the simple way to get this done.

Alternatively, you could write a simple module to track hits to your feeds, and record the number of unique hits to your feeds in a given period of time, say a week or a month.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that with google analytics.